# OpenCV how to crop circles detected using Hough transformin Java

Tags: java, opencv, crop

i want to crop the circles i detected using hough transform, i succeded to detect the circles but i didnt understand how to crop them.
here is  the code i used for hough transform:

```
for( int i=0;i<circles.cols();i++){
            Point center = new Point( Math.round(circles.get(0,i)[0]), 
            Math.round(circles.get(0, i)[1]));                      
            System.out.println("X============="+i+":"+circles.get(0,i)[0]);                                
            System.out.println("Y============="+i+":"+circles.get(0,i)[1]);
            int radius = (int) Math.round(circles.get(0, i)[2]);
            //System.out.println("--Rayon--:"+radius);
            Imgproc.circle( image, center, radius, new Scalar(0,0,255),3);//radius, color)   `
```

Comment: The result from the Hough circle transform gives you the center pixel and the radius. This should be enough to define a region of interest containing the circle, which you can insert into a new matrix to create a cropped image.

Comment: i didn't get the point,if u can explain more or give me an algorithm to follow, can you?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by crop? I've never used JavaCV but if you specify what you mean exactly I might be able to find a resource showing how to create ROIs or masks for the circle.

Comment: what i meant is i wanted to isolate the circles i detected using hough transform in a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can crop an image like this:

```
Mat initialImage = ...
Rect crop = new Rect(new Point(column,row),new Size(width,height)); // crop area begins at Point(column,row) with Size(width,height)
Mat croppedImage = new Mat(initialImage,crop);
```